# exporting data frames made of lists that contain more lists

Tags: list

[datafrane info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmIBS.png)
what is the easiest way to export those lists into a csv\xlsx?
Thank you.

I tried to export those lists, managed to get the workbook created, but it is empty.

```
# Create a new Excel workbook
output_file <- "E:/Lilush/posthoc_results.xlsx"  # Replace with your desired file path
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Iterate over each dependent variable
for (var in dependent_vars) {
  # Check if post hoc test results are available for the variable
  if (var %in% names(posthoc_results) && !is.null(posthoc_results[[var]])) {
    # Extract relevant information from the dunnTest object
    method <- posthoc_results[[var]]$method
    comparisons <- posthoc_results[[var]]$res$comparison
    p_values <- posthoc_results[[var]]$res$p.adj
    
    # Check if the extracted information has at least one row
    if (length(comparisons) > 0) {
      # Create a data frame with the extracted information
      dataset_summary <- data.frame(Method = method, Comparisons = comparisons, P_values = p_values)
      
      # Add a worksheet for the variable
      addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = var)
      
      # Write dataset summary to the worksheet
      writeData(wb, sheet = var, x = dataset_summary)
    }
  }
}

# Save the Excel workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, output_file)
```